# Check if parameter was sent to a function

Tags: erlang

I have the following case, a request is sent to my server, and I am parsing some GET parameters, in order to process it properly. After request is parsed, I am getting something like:

```
some_function(parameter1, parameter2, ...) ->
    some_steps_here.
```

The idea is that I want to be able to return nice error codes if some of these parameters are missing. E.g. if user did not enter `parameter1` into his url, I want to return the error instead of doing `some_steps_here`.

Was trying to solve it using pattern matching, but don't have idea how to do it at all.

Comment: What value exactly will you pass as `parameter1` if the user "did not enter parameter1 into his url"? Empty string? empty binary? nil? something else?

Comment: I have it parsed as `undefined`. So what I was trying to do is:
```some_function(param1, param2) when param1 == undefined ->
    Msg = util:format("Looks like ~p is missing", [param1]),
    response:send({502, Msg}, Req);
   some_function(param1, param2) -> main_handler_here```

Answer (score 3):

First, if you write `param1` and `param2` as lower letters, it means an `atom` and not a Parameter. You want your function to be:

```
some_function(Param1, Param2, ...)
```

Regarding your question, I'd suggest to use **function clauses** to catch a case where `Param1 == undefined` for example

```
some_function(undefined, _Param2, ...) ->
    io:format("Param1 is undefined~n");
some_function(_Param1, undefined, ...) ->
    io:format("Param2 is undefined~n");
some_function(Param1, Param2, ...) ->
    io:format("Params are OK!~n").
```

Every clause is separated by a `;` and the last clause is terminated by a dot `.`.

**Update:**

Answering the comment below: *Is there a way to make it more generic?*

It really depends on your implementation. You need to think what is your desired input and if you don't get the desired input, what will you get? A specific atom? Just a random atom instead of a list? Below I've added some other options you might also use. And please, take a look at [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) you will probably find all your answers there.

You can use guards to check for a specific type:

```
some_function(Param1, ...) when is_atom(Param1) -> 
    ...
some_function(Param1, ...) -> ...
```

Or, `case .. of` to check for something specific:

```
some_function(Param1, Param2, ...) ->
    case Param1=:=7 andalso is_list(Param2) of
        true  -> something;
        false -> something_else
    end.
```

Please see [this](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html) and [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions) for more information and examples.

Comment: Is there a way to make it more generic?  E.g. I don't want to write 4 same functions. Especially taking into account that they are returning almost same results

Comment: @OlegTarasenko Please see my edit. Also, please take a look at the links I referred to in my answer.